# How to use libudev on android

Tags: android, cross-compiling, udev

As a part of low-level monitoring application, that needs to monitor some changes in sysfs I should use udev interface instead of inotify. It's pretty clear that most of android devices, and all devices that I really need to run this application on, are using udev for enumerating devices and apply policies. The standard way to interact with udev from C-application is to use libudev (libudev.h), but there is no libudev.so in /lib directory and no include directory at all. So I need to get ARM port of this library or do some workaround here. Please, help me with this problem, since I'm not good in cross-compiling and libudev specific questions.

Note: I have root access on all devices, that I going to run this application on.

Comment: I have the same question. Although I havent had a solution, i have some progress which might be helpful to you. Please send me a message w/ your email address. We may discuss this issue together.

Comment: I have done similiar sort of implementation on Android but that is for libusb.I have created shared lib , pushed it and made a c application to interact with my USB device connected to host(Linux or Android).I am sure that using libusb there will be the similar port possible for libudev.Drop me a message or post a comment to this post if you need to discuss.

Comment: @Raulp could you elaborate your solution more please.

Comment: @Matical i have ported the libusb lib to android and using it to interact with the USB device.I can send reports to the device and the get the response from it.This is the summary.If you are more interested you can send me mail with your requirement.

Comment: @Sam did you fins a solution? I'm facing this issue now.